# Transform the constrained qubit-qutrit absolute separability Hilbert-Schmidt probability question into unconstrained form

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, integration, density-operator, eigenvalue

A quantum-mechanical "density" matrix is Hermitian (self-adjoint), positive definite, having trace 1. In terms of its four ordered eigenvalues ($\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \lambda_3 \geq \lambda_4$, $\Sigma_{i=1}^4 \lambda_i=1$), the  (Verstraete–Audenaert–de Moor) requirement that a generic (15-dimensional) "two-qubit" ($4 \times 4$) density matrix be "absolutely separable" (that is, cannot be entangled by unitary transformations) takes the form

\begin{equation}
\lambda_1-\lambda_3 -2 \sqrt{\lambda_2 \lambda_4} < 0.
\end{equation}

In sec. 3.3 of

[2009AbsoluteSeparabilityStudy](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0393044008001381#b34)

this requirement was enforced in computing (requiring an integration over the unit simplex of eigenvalues) the Hilbert-Schmidt absolute separability probability
\begin{equation}
\frac{29902415923}{497664}+\frac{-3217542976+5120883075 \pi -16386825840 \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}{32768 \sqrt{2}}=\frac{32 \left(29902415923-24433216974 \sqrt{2}\right)+248874917445 \sqrt{2} \left(5 \pi
   -16 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\right)}{15925248} \approx 0.00365826.
\end{equation}
for two-qubit systems.
An equivalent formula
\begin{equation}
\frac{29902415923}{497664}-\frac{50274109}{512 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{3072529845 \pi }{32768
   \sqrt{2}}+\frac{1024176615 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{4096 \sqrt{2}}
\end{equation}
was recently obtained by user JimB in his answer to
[MathematicaAnalysis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral)
.
This latter analysis (in contrast to the 2009 one) was based on a change-of-variables
\begin{equation}
\left\{\lambda _1\to \frac{x}{2 x+1},\lambda _2\to \frac{(x+1) y}{(2 x+1) (y+1)},\lambda
   _3\to \frac{(x+1) z}{(2 x+1) (y+1)}\right\}
\end{equation}
developed by N. Tessore so that the needed three-dimensional (setting $\lambda_4=1-\lambda_1-\lambda_2-\lambda_3$) integration would be of an unconstrained nature.

In explaining this transformation, Tessore had written:

"You get the change of variables by first noting that lambda1 + lambda2 + lambda3 < 1,
so that lambda1 = x, lambda2 = y (1-x), lambda3 = z (1-y) (1-x) suggests itself.
Performing that first change, you see that the limits suggest instead the
substitution x -> x/(1+x). Performing that second change, you are then
lead to y -> y/(1+x) in the same way. Noting that the resulting range of x
at this point is still 0 < x < 1, you can do a substitution x -> x/(1+x)
once more to get the change of variables."

Now, the question I would like to pose here is how one might develop/extend this set of transformations from its three-dimensional setting to a five-dimensional one,
so that the analogous "qubit-qutrit" absolute separability probability integration problem can be mapped into an unconstrained five-dimensional integration one.

[MathematicaQuestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230856/evaluate-3d-and-5d-constrained-integrals-for-absolute-separability-probabilitie)

The crucial piece-of-information needed at this stage of the question is that the requirement on the six ordered eigenvalues ($\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \lambda_3 \geq \lambda_4\geq \lambda_5\geq \lambda_6$, with $\lambda_6=1-\lambda_1-\lambda_2-\lambda_3-\lambda_4-\lambda_5$)   of a generic (35-dimensional) $6 \times 6$ density matrices takes the form
\begin{equation}
\lambda_1-\lambda_5 -2 \sqrt{\lambda_4 \lambda_6} < 0.
\end{equation}